# How do I improve this JS Parallax type math equation?

Tags: javascript, math

I'm having some troubles with this equation.

Essentially, I'd like the artboard (grid) div to position itself to the edge of the browser when the cursor is within 200px of the edge.

This can easily be done by setting the position by watching the mouse coords, however I'd like it to be fluid. I.E. If the mouse is 199px from the left edge then the lVal should slowly decrement until the artboard object edge is inline with the chrome edge.

At the moment, I have this working for the left edge but I can't figure out how to do it with the right without causing a slight pop.

Please review my example below.

http://dev.nimmbl.com/sampler/#

```
winSize[] = document window size (y,x)

2940 = width of artboard object


    function moveArtboard(e){    

    var t = docbody.offset(), space = 400, lVal, tVal;

    lVal = Math.round((space / 2) + (e.pageX - t.left) * (winSize[1] - (2940 + space)) / winSize[1]);
    tVal = Math.round((space / 2) + (e.pageY - t.top ) * (winSize[0] - (1200 + space)) / winSize[0]);

    if(lVal >= 0){
        artboard.obj.css({
            "left": 0,
            "top": tVal
        });
    } else if(lVal + -winSize[1] <= -2940){
        artboard.obj.css({
            "left": "auto",
            "right": 0,
            "top": tVal
        });
    } else {
        artboard.obj.css({
            "left": lVal,
            "top": tVal
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I think of it like this. There is an invisible frame that sits within the window that is 80% of the win size. The frame should be centered and the distance between the frame and the edge is the value that should be used as a multiplier. My goal is to show the left or right-most box without having the user scroll all the way to the edge of the browser chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I always find equations like this easier to deal with when you adjust the mouse position to be a % of what you want:

```
var percent = Math.min(1, Math.max(0, e.pageX - 200) / (winSize[1] - 400));
var lVal    = -percent * (2940 - winSize[1]);
var tVal    = Math.round((space / 2) + (e.pageY - t.top ) * (winSize[0] - (1200 + space)) / winSize[0]);

artboard.obj.css({
    left : lVal,
    top  : tVal
});
```

The two `Math` functions are to keep the value from 0-1 when it's close to the edge.  `percent` is now a number from 0-1, just multiply it by however much room you have to work with.

I'm pretty sure that's right, let me know if it's not perfect, haven't tested it.

I also have a `Math.constrain` function I wrote for cases like this:

```
Math.constrain = function(num, min, max){
    return num < min ? min : num > max ? max : num;
}

var percent = Math.constrain((e.pageX - 200) / (winSize[1] - 400), 0, 1);
```

Comment: Sorry, but math is not my strong suit, I've been tinkering around with this for a couple days. How would I use this in my current script?

Comment: Edited my answer, just try replacing most of your code (after the `var t = ...` line) with my first block of code

Comment: from your code: `var lVal = percent * (2940 - winSize[1]);` you need a `-` before percent per my code :)

Comment: hehe, pretty simple actually: `(e.pageX - 200) / (winSize[1] - 400)` will give you a number that's 0 at `x=200` and 1 at `x=winSize[1] - 200`.  It'll be negative to the left of `x=200` and >1 on the right side of the screen so the `Math.min` and `Math.max` statements just keep it between 0-1, throwing out the values if it's outside of that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dude!

```
function moveArtboard(e)
{
var t = docbody.offset(), 
    space = 400, 
    percent = Math.min(1, Math.max(0, e.pageX - (space/2)) / (winSize[1] - space)),
    vPercent = Math.min(1, Math.max(0, e.pageY - (space/2)) / (winSize[0] - space)),
    lVal    = -percent * (2940 - winSize[1]),
    tVal    = -vPercent * (1200 - winSize[0]);

artboard.obj.css({
    left : lVal,
    top  : tVal
});
}
```